# How get Maven war-app fully functional in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, eclipse-wtp, maven-eclipse-plugin

Any input on how to get Maven war-app fully setup in Eclipse as "Dynamic Web Project"?

We have a webproject setup and working in Maven3.

Using Eclipse-Indigo, latest version, and running

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

to import it into Eclipse.

This works fine for the Java-files compilation, 
but cannot build a war-file and deploy to an appserver defined in Eclipse.
Would be nice to get that working, too.

(I read that you can use m2eclipse for this, but I sincerely hate it, because (at least some months ago when I last tried it) it's still ridiculously slow to build a reasonably large/complex application -- like it said "Build Project and go have a coffee" in the menu).

I now saw, however, that you can also do

```
  mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=[version]
```

Problem, according to documentation

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html

is that [version] can only be "R7", "1.0", or "1.5".
That seems like awfully old versions...

According to WTP documentation

http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#What_version_of_Eclipse_does_WTP_work_with.3F

that would require you to downgrade to Eclipse-3.2 from way-back-when...

So anybody has a reasonable solution to this?

Can it also somehow work with recent versions of Eclipse and WTP?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `maven-eclipse-plugin`.

Instead use Eclipse's own [m2e plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).

If you follow the link, there is a video that will help you get started.

m2e is officially integrated with WTP and, from my experience, works very well.